# Manipulating Text with JavaScript Based on Checkbox State

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple HTML page that presents a user with several options via checkboxes. I need to generate a string, stored in a variable that I can use on the page when a button is clicked, which will vary based on which boxes are checked.

The string will be a URL ("http://example.com/index.htm&term=") and will need to have additional text appended to it for each checkbox that is checked.

For example, if only a single box, say box1, is checked the string "box1" should be appended to the URL variable to look like "http://example.com/index.htm&term=box1"

If, however more than one box is checked, say box2 and box3 are checked, then the string "box2%20OR%20box3" should be appended to the URL string.

I'm pretty sure this can be done with JavaScript but I have no experience with it and would appreciate some guidance/examples.

Comment: Use `querySelectorAll` and use the parameter  `"input[type='checkbox']"` to select all checkboxes. You will get an array of checkbox elements that you can loop through to see if they are checked or not, and build your URL from that. Good luck! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing it in a variable, I would recommend calling a function that builds the link when the button is pressed. If you really wanted to put it in a variable though, you would set up an event listener for the `change` event for each checkbox, and call the function to update the variable each time one of the checkboxes is checked or unchecked.

```js
function checkboxUrl(checkboxes) {
    const
        url = `http://example.com/index.html`,
        checkedArray = [];

    for (let checkbox of checkboxes) {
        if (checkbox.checked) checkedArray.push(checkbox);
    };
    
    const checkboxString = checkedArray.map(checkbox => checkbox.value).join(`%20OR%20`);
    return url + (checkboxString ? `?term=` + checkboxString : ``);
}

let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(`input[type='checkbox']`);
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label><input type='checkbox' value='box1'>box1</label>
<label><input type='checkbox' value='box2'>box2</label>
<label><input type='checkbox' value='box3'>box3</label>
<button onclick='console.log(checkboxUrl(checkboxes))'>Get URL</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Jquery](https://jquery.com/) you can do something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="box1">
<input type="checkbox" id="box2">
<button type="button" id="myButton">Submit</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myButton').click(function(){
        var url = 'www.myurl.com/index.html&term=';
        var checkboxList = [];
        var params = '';

        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(){
            checkboxList.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });

        params = checkboxList.join('%'); //will output "box1%box2"
        url += params //www.myurl.com/index.html&term=box1%box2

        window.location.href = url;
    });
});
</script>
```